# Restrict field length to exactly 10 characters of a particular item in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Whenever the user clicks on `Release` button, the release form is opened.  There we can enter an invoice number. I want to restrict the invoice number to exactly equal to 10 characters.

Now I am using:

```
trigger: when-validate-record  
trigger object:Release   
condition:`length(:Release.RA_INVOICE_NUMBER) <> 10` 

action tab   
message error : invoice must be equal to 10 characters
```

Now here is the problem.

If user enters a invoice number which is not equal to 10 characters and press **ok** button the error message is shown and this is fine. But if the user clicks on **cancel** button or cross mark once,  after the error message is shown the release form is exited and the status of invoice is changing to *released* even if the invoice number is not 10 characters.

Please tell me how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
raise form_trigger_failure
```

after displaying the message to cause an exception and break the flow.

Comment: thanks sathya for your reply......but the problem is standard trigger to change the status from approved to released is firing first before any form personalization trigger including my error message trigger